# Accessing and Setting Application Variables From QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to access ASP.NET MVC application-level variables from a method called using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Application["SomeCachedData"] == null)
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
    {
        var someCachedData = LongRunningDataLoadMethod();
        HttpContext.Current.Application["SomeCachedData"] = someCachedData;
    });
}
```

I know I can use other caching libraries to accomplish this, but I would like to limit the complexity of the solution.

Comment: I cannot think why not. Why don't you test it out? It should be as simple as trying it.

Comment: I tried it before I posted the question.  It doesn't seem to work, but I thought there may be some trick to doing it that I just don't know (and can't find via search)

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Error or what? To start with: *QueueBackgroundWorkItem takes a Task-returning callback; the work item will be considered finished when the callback returns.* but you are not returning a task as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx)